# how to replace NA with the value that later input with same ID and date

Tags: r, replace

I have a data that looks and I want to filled n/a with the result that is later input with same ID and test_date, and only keep one record for each ID each day.
What should I do?

Here is the codes for sample data:

```
ID <-c("1", "1", "1","2", "2")
Test_date <-c("2020-07-09", "2020-07-09","2020-07-09", "2020-07-07","2020-07-08")
Art <-c("N/A","D","N/A","N/A", "B")
PE<-c("N/A","N/A","B","A","N/A")

Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Test_date, Art, PE)
```

Comment: is the NA an actual `<NA>` or the characters `"N/A"`

Comment: Can you give a solution for both cases? I am new to r, so I build the sample data for the question, maybe I will run into both case in the real life. Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking about is called *imputation*, and there are several techniques and opinions about it. This is actually two questions, in a sense: (1) how to replace `NA` (or NA-like strings) with the next value? (2) how to do something per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Base-R

First change character strings `"N/A"` to actual `NA`

```
Sample.data[Sample.data=="N/A"] <- NA
```

now the the real meat of the answer

```
merge(
    aggregate(Art ~ ID + Test_date, Sample.data, paste),
    aggregate(PE ~ ID + Test_date, Sample.data, paste),
    all=T
)
```

output:

```
  ID  Test_date  Art   PE
1  1 2020-07-09    D    B
2  2 2020-07-07 <NA>    A
3  2 2020-07-08    B <NA>
```

Comment: How is this doing *"filled n/a with the result that is later input with same ID and test_date"*? `ID=2` and `Test_date=2020-07-07` should have `Art=B`. Perhaps I misunderstood the need for "filling" (despite the pic that matches your output).

Comment: @r2evans, `Art=B` is from a different date, OP wants it only from the same ID and **Test_Date**

Comment: (As I'm looking more into my interpretation of the question and yours :-), is there a reason you chose `paste` as the aggregating function? It appears to produce the same results with `c`, `dplyr::first`, `min`, `max`, ... I think the main function of `aggregate` here is actually in its `na.action=` argument, which by default is analogous to `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: ... and **that** is what I had misread. Thanks, DanielO, spot-on. (Though my comment on `aggregate` and `c` still stands :-)

Comment: @r2evans, I wanted to remain in Base, the use of `aggregate` with `paste` is in case there are multiple values in a give ID/Date. if you change the data to `Art <-c("G","D","N/A","N/A", "B")` and Run my code, you'll see why I chose that. It will collapse all possibilities into a single line. (collapse may not be the best word as they are actually put into a list. the `collapse` argument is not used).

Comment: ...Never mind, I see what you mean, `c` gives the same results as `paste`. in fact `c` is more versatile in case there are numeric values. `paste` would be useful if you didn't want a list but rater a collapse string. `...FUN = paste, collapse = ", ")`

Answer (score 0):

(**Edited** to correct my misgrouping.)

I'm going to suggest a tidyverse solution to be expeditious, though this can be done (with a little more effort) in base R (and `data.table`).

A few tasks:

- replace `"N/A"` (which is a completely valid and definite string) with `NA` (actually, `NA_character_`, since there are over six types of NA in R);
- convert `Test_date` to a real `Date` class, and order by this;
- fill up by group;
- group by id/date and keep only one

The first few are done with

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # fill
Sample.data %>%
  mutate(Test_date = as.Date(Test_date)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Art, PE), ~ replace(., . == "N/A", NA_character_)) %>%
  arrange(Test_date) %>%
  group_by(ID, Test_date) %>%
  tidyr::fill(., Art, PE, .direction = "up") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   ID    Test_date  Art   PE   
#   <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr>
# 1 2     2020-07-07 <NA>  A    
# 2 2     2020-07-08 B     <NA> 
# 3 1     2020-07-09 D     B    
# 4 1     2020-07-09 D     B    
# 5 1     2020-07-09 <NA>  B
```

though you need to think about what happens when your *last* observation is `NA`.

Now for your last point

> *and only keep one record for each ID each day*

I'll expand the above with a little more. I'm going to infer *first*, but frankly you haven't provided enough information to know if it should be first, last, sum, max, row-with-the-fewest-`NA`-values, or whatever.

```r
Sample.data %>%
  mutate(Test_date = as.Date(Test_date)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Art, PE), ~ replace(., . == "N/A", NA_character_)) %>%
  arrange(Test_date) %>%
  group_by(ID, Test_date) %>%
  tidyr::fill(., Art, PE, .direction = "up") %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   ID    Test_date  Art   PE   
#   <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr>
# 1 1     2020-07-09 D     B    
# 2 2     2020-07-07 <NA>  A    
# 3 2     2020-07-08 B     <NA>
```

Comment: _"this can be done (with a little more effort) in base R"_ I thought my Base-R answer was  somewhat less effort. I agree with you statement that there is not enough information. My answer will return every non-NA item found so that the list is collapsed to a single entry for ever individual `ID`+`Date` split

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(Sample.data)
# Format NA properly as NA 
Sample.data[, c("Art", "PE") := lapply(.SD, function(x) fifelse(x == "N/A", NA_character_, x)), .SDcols = c("Art", "PE")]

Sample.data[, .(Art[!is.na(Art)], PE[!is.na(PE)]), by = .(ID, Test_date)]
#    ID  Test_date   V1   V2
# 1:  1 2020-07-09    D    B
# 2:  2 2020-07-07 <NA>    A
# 3:  2 2020-07-08    B <NA>
```

Alternatively:

```
Sample.data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = .(ID, Test_date)]
```